# Smartphone Bluetooth Antenna Modification

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, pcb-design, pcb-antenna, patch-antenna

Is it possible to modify **smartphone Bluetooth antenna (2.4 GHz)** by redesigning it? I am currently designing a Polyimide microstrip patch antenna with **50 ohms impedance**. What steps should I make so that the device won't face heating and what are the **circuitry modification** (resistor and capacitor) to match the 50 ohms impedance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in terms of end-goal?  Matching impedance for annRF antenna is a complex task and depends very much on the exact physical layout, you won’t get a list of component values from some guy on the internet.

Comment: Bluetooth operates at very low output power. No idea why one would face heating problems on the antenna side, there is not enough power to cause any heating that is noticable by a human.

Comment: Guys. Is it possible to modify the smartphone Bluetooth antenna?